# Layout Cycle Detected in Windows 10 but not in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal

I am using a timer that updates the layout every 10 seconds till the Progress bar isn't filled completely.

There seems to be no issue in Windows 8.1 but in Windows 10, Layout Cycle Detected Exception is thrown.

Comment: Take a look at the remarks section of this [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.layoutcycleexception.aspx) to see if it gives you any ideas

Comment: @MarkHall  I was able to identify the issue. I was attempting to set New Vertical & Horizontal Offset. The Values seem to be changing on their own causing the Layout Updated to be in an infinite Loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code was

```
private void SetVerticalOffSet()
        {
            Popup ParentPopup = this.Parent as Popup;

            if (ParentPopup == null)
                return;

            double ActualVerticalOffset = ParentPopup.VerticalOffset;
            double ActualHorizontalOffset = ParentPopup.HorizontalOffset;

            double NewVerticalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height - DecryptionDialog_MainGrid.ActualHeight) / 2;
            double NewHorizontalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width - DecryptionDialog_MainGrid.ActualWidth) / 2;
            if (ActualVerticalOffset != NewVerticalOffset || ActualHorizontalOffset != NewHorizontalOffset)
            {
                ParentPopup.VerticalOffset = NewVerticalOffset;
                ParentPopup.HorizontalOffset = NewHorizontalOffset;
            }
        }
```

It was invoked every time the layout was updated.

The if block caused an infinite loop as The ActualVerticalOffSet & ActualHorizontalOffSet kept changing in Windows 10. (in the 10th position of decimal)

```
if (ActualVerticalOffset != NewVerticalOffset || ActualHorizontalOffset != NewHorizontalOffset)
        {
            ParentPopup.VerticalOffset = NewVerticalOffset;
            ParentPopup.HorizontalOffset = NewHorizontalOffset;
        }
```

The Tentative Solution to this fix is

```
if (Math.Round(ActualVerticalOffset) != Math.Round(NewVerticalOffset) ||     Math.Round(ActualHorizontalOffset) != Math.Round(NewHorizontalOffset))
{
        ParentPopup.VerticalOffset = NewVerticalOffset;
        ParentPopup.HorizontalOffset = NewHorizontalOffset;
}
```

Up until Microsoft comes